# Angular JS Multiple filter with single ng-model / input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to make a single Search to filter multiple objects value ??

For e.g: if i search '1' OR 'one' then the result should come........

I've tried it so far:

HTML:

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="model_search">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="obj_data in data | filter:{id:model_search, text:model_search}">{{obj_data.id}}-->{{obj_data.text}}</li>
    </ul>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "text": 'one'
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "text": 'two'
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "text": 'three'
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "text": 'four'
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "text": 'five'
  }];
```

});

[DEMO PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/9dhmFvzjEUflUWc91dcE?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You were close, just change the filter to look like this:

```
 <li ng-repeat="obj_data in data | filter:model_search">{{obj_data.id}}-->{{obj_data.text}}</li>
```

Working plunkr below
http://plnkr.co/edit/0jeA0u8oaz16cYnsZjfw?p=preview

Comment: Thx link64. But what if i only want search for `id` & `text` ??

Comment: You will most likely need to write a custom filter